# HttpResponse[Status=Found, StatusCode=302]" while integrating Salesforce to AzureDevops

Tags: salesforce, azure-devops-rest-api, sfdc, salesforce-rest-api

Integrating Salesforce to Azuredevops,
Creating Issue/Task/Bug to Azuredevops from the Salesforce custom page by using POST method RestApi.
Doing the same from postman service by using same url ,accesstoken etc and i am able to create task in the Azuredevops.

But issue is when i try the same from salesforce I am getting the response back as

**"System.HttpResponse[Status=Found, StatusCode=302]"** and  `<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body> <h2>Object moved to <a                             href="https://*******.*****.visualstudio.com/_signin*********************`

I am using Namedcredential in the salesforce,
and written code like below,

```
Httprequest request = new HttpRequest();
Http http = new Http();        
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setEndpoint('callout:Namedcred' + '/*****/******/_apis/wit/workitems/$issue?api-version=6.0' );
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json-patch+json');            
request.setHeader('Authorization',  '{!$Credential.Password}');
request.setBody(requestBody);
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
```

I tried the same from the postman service and everything working good and also getting 200 OK status

Comment: Hello, i hope that couple of spaces are only added by mistake ? :) are you using a https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP ?? I have similar problem with authentication and i use a PAT as a BASE64 and that helps

Comment: @Cezu Yes those spaces were added by mistake while posting here ,I corrected that now.
url using is ,  
https://dev.azure.com/*****/******/_apis/wit/workitems/$issue?api-version=6.0

PYI: 
*******/******/is my official azuredevops project name

Comment: I think there is a problem with authentication are you using a PAT ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows and try to convert your password using :  ```String myBase64String = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueof(myString));```

Comment: @Cezu Yes i am Using PAT.After the conversion i am getting unauthorised error.